# Limit of the modulus of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Given $\alpha\left(\lambda\right)=\left(1-\lambda\right)+\lambda\alpha$ where $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha$ is a complex number, consider the function $f_{\lambda}=\|\alpha\left(\lambda\right)\|^{\frac{1}{\lambda}}$. Obviously $\|\alpha\left(\lambda\right)\|$ is the modulus of $\alpha\left(\lambda\right)$. The limit of $f_{\lambda}$ for $\lambda$ going to zero is given by $e^{Re\left(\alpha\right)-1}$ where $Re\left(\alpha\right)$ is the real part of $\alpha$.
How do you derive this result?

Comment: In Spanish we say ``por Fuerza Bruta". Just write $\alpha=a+ib$ and expand everything. Take into account that $(1+f(t))^{1/f(t)}\to e$ if $f(t)\to0$.

Answer (score 0):

If you write $\alpha=a+bi$ and expand the module, you'll get that
$$f(\lambda)=\left( 1 + 2 (-1 + a) \lambda + (1 - 2 a + a^2 + b^2) \lambda^2\right)^{1/2\lambda} = \left[\left( 1 + 2 (-1 + a) \lambda + (1 - 2 a + a^2 + b^2) \lambda^2\right)^{\frac{1}{ 2 (-1 + a) \lambda + (1 - 2 a + a^2 + b^2) \lambda^2}} \right]^{\frac{ 2 (-1 + a) \lambda + (1 - 2 a + a^2 + b^2) \lambda^2}{2\lambda}}
$$

The part in Brackets goes to $e$ as $\lambda$ goes to $0$.

The exponent $\dfrac{2 (-1 + a) \lambda + (1 - 2 a + a^2 + b^2) \lambda^2}{2\lambda}$ clearly goes to $-1+a$.

So you're done.